# Wordpress: Manually add class to post_class with an array?

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I'm currently working with the following line of code:

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes); ?>>
```

I basically wish to add the class 'thumbnail' to this list item manually. I tried the following, but it stopped it from retrieving any classes.

```
 <li <?php post_class( $classes, 'thumbnail' ); ?>>
```

Can anyone help me out as to how to format this correctly? I'm kinda new to php and wordpress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply add a new member to `$classes` like so:

`<li <?php $classes[] = 'thumbnail'; post_class( $classes ); ?>>`

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned, this is a snippet of code from Woocommerce. If I change it this much, is it likely to stop it from working? Also where would I put the array $classes into the snippet you replied? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just updated, much simpler than I thought :} this adds 'thumbnail' to the other array passed from Woo